# Easy way to find un-parented stories

Tags: azure-devops

I had been adding a lot of stories these days to a VSTS project. Some of them have parent Features. Is there a way to list all stories with their parents and thus find out which all are unparented.

Right now, I have to open each story and find it out myself on whether its parented or not.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use **work item query** to achieve this. There is a filter [**work items and direct links**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies)

[image]

For your situation, you need to select **Only return items that do not have matching links** with parent link types, detail query please refer below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: In the last screenshot, if I enter 'Value' column as 'User Story' how would the query perform. I was expecting the same result, but the results did not make any sense. Why is that so?

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu Not sure if  got your point, in the screenshot there are two lines of `work item type = value`. If you mean you changed the second work item value from `any` to `User Story` in the screenshot. This query will get  all  user story work items  and exclude the ones which parent is also user story work item . In other words, unlike the `value = any`  only found the  un-parented stories, this query will also get some user story work items which have feature/bug... parent work item.

Comment: You got the exact point that I had asked. But still I am confused. Say, to create a query for unparented story that has tasks, how will I create it? I can use the exact same query that you had mentioned, and instead of `Any` in the second `work item type` I have to mention `task`, right? I haven't completely understtood the use of the second filter yet.

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu The second line of `work item type=value` is the filter for **the linked work item**, you can also add new clause by +.  The key is the Filter Option: Only return items that do not have matching links. If you select   task in the second work item type, this will not query for unparented story that has tasks, this will only query for the user story that  has no parents and has parents the work item could be any just excluded   task. For example, if you have a work item ID 18, it has a parent , and parent is task. You could not got the workitem 18 when you run the query.

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu If it's a litter hard to understand the use of the second filter, suggest you change the  Filter options to **only return items that have matching links** and do some test for the second filter, it's much easy to understand it.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of creating a Query you can go to the Backlog and choose "Parents" in the view option menu. In the backlog list at the bottom is a group of unparented stories. This is probably a new feature made after the question was asked.

Adding the image so its easy to find

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see the Parents option? I'm using Azure DevOps, not sure if I'm missing any permissions/roles/?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to achieve this by just leaving the parent field empty when creating your query. See example, add all relevant filters to get the appropriate user stories and then leave the Parent filter to blank in the query
[query example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O03O2.png)